# how to generate multi layers of material in both x and z axes on abaqus subroutine code?

Tags: fortran, abaqus

this is the ABAQUS SUBROUTINE code written in fortran  that I use to generate the motion of a heat source in x-axis, I want the code to realize that I have several material layers in z-axis, where for each z-layer need the heat source to move across the  x-direction I am using this code to simulate a thermal model for a material on ABAQUS software, the code worked fine when I had only one layer in z-axis, now I have multiple layers build up in both x and z direction and I tried the following code but it's not working, please if you can suggest any modifications :)
ps: the following pic was the simulation for only one layer in z-axes, I want to repeat the same process and heat source movment but for multiple layers in z-direction

```
      SUBROUTINE DFLUX(FLUX,SOL,KSTEP,KINC,TIME,NOEL,NPT,COORDS,
     1 JLTYP,TEMP,PRESS,SNAME)
C
      INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'
C
      DIMENSION FLUX(2), TIME(2), COORDS(3)
      CHARACTER*80 SNAME


      X=COORDS(1)
      Y=COORDS(2)
      Z=COORDS(3)
      T=TIME(2)
      X0=0.0
      Y0=0.0
      Z0=0.0
      Q=2000
      R0=0.0075
      R0=R0**2
      PI=3.141593
      V=0.01

      XC=X0+V*T
      YC=Y0
      ZC=Z0
      ETTA=0.7

      FLUX(1)=0

      Q0=((3*Q*ETTA)/(PI*R0))*EXP((-3*((X-XC)**2+(Y-YC)**2))/R0)

      IF(((X-XC)**2+(Y-YC)**2)<R0)  THEN
      FLUX(1)=Q0

      END IF
      FLUX(2)=0.0


          XC=X0+V*T
      YC=Y0
      ZC=Z0+0.05
      ETTA=0.7

      FLUX(1)=0

      Q0=((3*Q*ETTA)/(PI*R0))*EXP((-3*((X-XC)**2+(Y-YC)**2))/R0)

      IF(((X-XC)**2+(Y-YC)**2)<R0)  THEN
      FLUX(1)=Q0

      END IF
      FLUX(2)=0.0


      RETURN
      END
```

[image]

Comment: Please use `IMPLICIT NONE` in your Fortran programs. For you own sanity.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to consider here:

- There seems to be a mistake in the coordinate variables: the 3 components are all being attributed to X (instead of `X=COORDS(1)`, `Y=COORDS(2)`, ...). These coordinates should be that of the integration point where the subroutine is called: if you have multiple layers, they should be different.
- If (x,y,z) is not enough, the variable `NPT` has information about the integration point.

As an additional note, I'd be careful with non-declared variables.

Comment: Hello, that was fixed in my code , they were assigned to x,y,z that's how I managed to generate the 1st layer.                                                                                                         but could yu please advice on how to fix the code to make it more suited for multiple layers generation ? thank you in advance :)

Comment: The subroutine is called at every integration point -> every layer has its integration points. So the z component should be different across different layers. Your `Q0` equation does not seem to depend on `z`.

Comment: yes I know that's because the heat source only moves in the x-axes ,and what changes is that an extra material layer is built so a new value for z is generated now for the new layer but the heat source moves only in the x direction of that layer, any idea how to repeat this movment of the heat source for each value of this given values of z (0.05,0.025) = repeating this  heat source motion for 2 extra generated material layer, any idea how to do that ?